# Binding an TypeScript / Angular 7 Enum to an Ionic 4 ion-select

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Apologies if I have any terminology wrong; I'm new to the entire IONIC stack and uncertain where one layer ends and another begins.

I'm having a series of challenges working with TypeScript enums, and binding them through to an `ion-select`.  All of the mentions I've found reference older versions of TypeScript, Angular, or IONIC, and I seem to be missing some important understandings.

Note that I have it working now, it's just- messy and I suspect there is a better way.

Here's specifically what I'm trying to accomplish-

1. Define an enum, with integer values (trivial)
2. Use that enum as a property within a class, which will be passed to a REST API and stored in MongoDB. (trivial)
3. In the "add" and "edit" UIs, bind an instance of that class. The enum property of the object will be two-way databound to an `ion-select`.
4. On page load, populate the `ion-select` with the full set of possible enums, using the name as the displayed text, and the integer value as the value.

Here's how I've done it currently;

Enum;

```
export enum UserType {
    SystemAdmin = 1,
    SchoolAdmin = 10,
    DepartmentAdmin = 20,
    Teacher = 50,
    Student = 100,
}
```

Key parts of the class containing it;

```
export class UserData {
    userType: UserType = UserType.Student; // string;
    name: string;
    ...
}
```

I've initialized the field in the above example, in case that was part of the problem.

Excerpted IONIC UI typescript;

```
import { UserData, UserType } from 'models/user.dto';
export class UserEditPageimplements OnInit {

    // for access to the Enums, within this context, 
    // needed for template access? 
    get userTypes() { return UserType; }

    // the user data, retrieved from an API 
    user = new UserData();

    // HACK: getters/setters which
    // 1. give me access to the object property
    // 2. convert it to/from a string, for the ion-select
    get getUserType(): string {
        return this.user.userType.toString();
    }
    set getUserType(u: string) {
        this.user.userType = +u;
    }

    // Provides access to the Keys array of the enum 
    userTypeKeys = Object.keys(UserType);

    ...
}
```

And relevant HTML;

In this example, I'm just attempting the binding the value;
I can confirm this is getting loaded correctly in `ngInit`.

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="getUserType"> 
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let t of userTypeKeys;" value="{{ t }}">{{ userTypes[t] }}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Overall it works but there is a huge amount of hack in the supporting code.

In particular;

- Can I bind the ion-select to an integer value and/or convert it to a string value in the HTML.  I can convert a string to a number, e.g. "+foo" but I'm not aware of an in-HTML syntax to convert a number to a string.
- I'd like to get rid of `userTypes()`, and reference `UserType` directly.
- I'd like to eliminate the get/set `getUserType()`, and use the object's `userType` property directly, OR at least move the get/set inside the class (I get no binding result, when I try binding `ion-select` directly to any class properties.
- I'd like to eliminate `userTypeKeys` if possible as well.

Thanks for any suggestions.